# Trouble Using sed to find all string within double quotes

Tags: php, linux, ssh, sed, command-line-interface

So I have this code that I use post hostname, username, and password within a .php webpage. I then am able to SSH into my remote Pi, and change the text for textfile.txt. What I need now is to be able to show the results into my confirmation webpage. I am having trouble understanding if sed is the right thing to use, but this is what I have so far.

**This is the testfile.txt example I'm using:**

Pi1Hostname = "Tester1"

Pi1Username = "ExampleUsername"

Pi1Password = "ExamplePassword"

**This is the working script to input a new string into hostname:**

```
    $ssh1->exec('sed -i \'/Pi1Hostname /s/".*."/"'. $hostnameNew .'\"/\' testfile.txt');
```

**This is what i'm currently trying to use to call the pi1Hostname Results:**

```
echo '<p>Company:' . $ssh1->exec('sed -i /Pi1Hostname /\".*.\"/ testfile.txt') .'</p>';
```

**This is the Error message I'm getting:**

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unterminated address regex
```

If anyone has some input on this problem I'm having it'd be much appreciated. This is the one thing that I need to figure out to get the other 19 lines of input for my webpage.

Comment: You can add multiple `-e` arguments to sed to process multiple replacements in one command line.

Answer (score 1):

After looking, I found the answer I was kinda looking for:

```
cat testfile.txt | grep -oP 'Pi1Hostname = "\K[^"]+
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the sed invocation to work on your test file before adding it into your program.  I do that with any command I hard code into another program.

Your sed invocation doesn't quote the expression argument, which has spaces.  That's why it's not working.

I have a few other thoughts for you.

You should be very careful to escape any data that comes into a form input from the internet.  A carefully crafted form of could inject a command into your shell ( I may be missing how this fits together).  Also make sure this is running over https.  It seems that your payload had anything anyone would need to look into your pi - not something you want any unencrypted.  For that matter, it would protect your pi from submitting it's username and password  to a phishing  it mitm style attack.

Furthermore, why use a shell at all?  You're already in php, aren't you?  You have access to the full set of general propose programming language capabilities, including regular expressions with pcre (not just crummy standard regexes from unix, no offense sed my friend).  Wouldn't it make more sense to read the whole file, parse it on the php side?

Comment: This is all testing phase. The final version will be all secured on a private network that only the administrator on the main Pi, or within the private IP Scheme with Admin User privileges  will have access to the website. I need it to influence 5 Pi's to set a series of settings automatically.